# Flatten the base of STL file & cut it into a regular shape

Tags: edit-mode, extrude

I want to flatten the base of [my STL file](https://www.dropbox.com/s/by7fdw49x05savj/terrain_test01.stl?dl=0) & cut it into a regular shape (e.g., round, square...). 
The results I expected should be the same as this video shows (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bSNy9iUqDbI). I tried but I did not succeed with his method in blender. 
If anyone can help me, I would be appreciated. It is best to give a detailed method because I am a beginner in this. Thank you in advance.
My STL file is here: https://www.dropbox.com/s/by7fdw49x05savj/terrain_test01.stl?dl=0.

Comment: Please use the [edit] link at the bottom of your question (https://i.stack.imgur.com/lXFuK.png) and add images that might help us understand your scene and settings. ( to learn how to post images [read this link:](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491))

Answer (score 2):

1. Import model from stl format
   [image: Import model from stl]
2. In edit mode, select all vertices and delete duplicates (Merge distance in 2.80) with desired accuracy
   [image: delete duplicates]
3. Select all faces in edit mode and Extrude it down
   [image: extrude]
4. Resize selected faces by Z axis to 0, align it by lowest vertice of top surface
   [image: resize]
5. Select all faces, again remove duplicate vertices and Recalculate Normals (if everything fine you do not need to make it Inside)
   [image: recalculate]
6. Add Cylinder object and make it right
   [image: cylinder]
7. In edit mode remove cylinder top face, select all leftover faces and Extrude region to cover the main object
   [image: cover the main object]
8. Add Boolean modifier to Terrain and set up Difference with Cylinder
   [image: result]
9. [Profit!](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1meiFshS-pmEycgT27Ht5HTYkVWcLXYVc/view?usp=sharing)